# .NET Moles Stub Fallthrough Behaviour

Tags: moles

Is it possible in the .NET Moles framework to use the Fallthrough Behavior in Stub Types as we do with Mole Types?

I can override the default behavior of a Mole instance by doing:

```
MMyInstance.InstanceBehavior = MoleBehaviors.Fallthrough;
```

However for a Stub Instance i can´t find in the BehavedBehaviors class the corresponding behavior.

I'm using version 0.94

Thanks
Hugo Pais

Answer (score 4):

It is explained in the manual at "Partial Stubs". What you want is CallBase, which is a property of Stubs of Moles :

```
var stub = new SMyInstance() {CallBase = true};
```

or

```
stub.CallBase = true;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: According to my understanding, the manual only allows you to perform this feat for 'virtual' methods, as described in the text: 

"Partial stubs occur when you are stubbing classes and allow you to stub a part of the members only. When a virtual member is not stubbed, the base method is called instead of the behavior. The partial stub mode can be turned on through the CallBase property, which stubs of classes implement (from the IPartialStub interface)."