# Assigning to a stub class method in Moles while using partial stubs

Tags: moles

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682031/net-moles-stub-fallthrough-behaviour) regarding partial stubs, but it does not quite tell me what I need to know.

I understand that, if I am using a Moles stub for a class (let's say, for `DataService`, I'm using `SDataService`), I can set the `CallBase` property to `true` so that, if there is no delegate for a particular method, the base implementation's method will be called.  Great, but how do I assign a delegate to a particular method in this case?

If there is no way to do that, say I have an interface `IDataService` that I stub using `SIDataService`.  I can easily assign a delegate to a method here.  But, how do I tell it to call the corresponding method on `DataService` (an implementation of `IDataService`) if there is no delegate for a given method?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I see now that the method needs to be virtual to be overridden in the first scenario above.  I don't think that makes a whole lot of sense, but it is what it is.

So, focusing on the second scenario, would I have to create a `Behavior`?  (And why isn't there one already for stubs like there is for moles?)  Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Can you give a code sample? Have you looked at the MInterdaces? If the method is not virtual, you can make a Mock in the MInterface of your class.

Comment: @peer I didn't initially see that the method needed to be virtual.  This is not in a Pex context -- can I use `MInterface` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Delegates (detours) are set to stubs types the same way as mole types.  For example,  SIDataService.GetMemberProfile() is configured to return a mock object like this:

```
var memberMock = new Member() { Firstname="Joe", LastName="Schmoe" };
var stub = new SIDataService();
stub.GetMemberProfileMember = i => memberMock;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite answer the question.  I'm looking for a way to default to the method of an actual object short of creating a delegate for every method.  In other words, I want all the methods for which I did *not* define a delegate to use a particular object's methods.