# Microsoft Moles : circular reference error?

Tags: unit-testing, moles, stub, circular-reference

I've the following Entity Framework entities:

```
public class Country
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? Country_Id { get; set; }
    public Country HomeCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Moles has generated **MPerson** and **MCountry** stub classes.

Now I do want to stub the set of the Country_Id:

```
MPerson.AllInstances.Country_IdSetNullableOfInt64 = (Person instance, long? id) =>
{
    // Do something

    // Set the Country_Id to the provided id
    // This will trigger this same method again and again. How to avoid this ?
    instance.Country_Id = id;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682031/net-moles-stub-fallthrough-behaviour) gives the answer:

```
MolesContext.ExecuteWithoutMoles(() => instance.Country_Id = id);
```